# Magic Keyboard on Windows - How to get Media keys to work

Tags: keyboard, windows

I'd like to purchase a magic apple keyboard for my windows pc. Do media keys like playing music, volume controls, and so on work on windows?

Is there a way to map keys correctly on windows for all media/functions to work?

Answer (score 1):

I would assume the media keys on the Magic Keyboard would work with Windows 10, if the following were true.

- The Boot Camp Assistant was used to install Windows 10.
- The model Mac is listed under Compatibility at the Apple [Magic Keyboard](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MLA22LL/A/magic-keyboard-us-english?afid=p238%7Csud9iaotp-dc_mtid_1870765e38482_pcrid_246386725860_pgrid_14874603010_&cid=aos-us-kwgo-pla-btb--slid---product-MLA22LL/A) website.
- Under Windows settings, the Apple keyboard is chosen as the current input method. See image below.

  [image]